# implementing mapTree function

Tags: dictionary, haskell, binary-tree

i am asket to Define the function:

```
treeMap :: (a -> b) -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree b
```

Which takes a function and a binary tree, and produces a binary tree in which all nodes are the result of applying the function on the given tree

the binary tree is:

```
data BinaryTree a = Nil | BNode a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)
```

and my code doesnt complie. i am getting an error of:

```
error: Not in scope: data constructor ‘BinaryTree’
treeMap f (BNode x (BinaryTree l) (BinaryTree r)) =    |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

my code:

```
data BinaryTree a = Nil | BNode a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)

treeMap :: (a -> b) -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree b
treeMap f Nil  = Nil
treeMap f (BNode x (BinaryTree l) (BinaryTree r)) =
    BNode (f x) (BinaryTree (treeMap f l)) (BinaryTree (treeMap f r))
```

Comment: Do you understand the compiler error?

Comment: the error means that the pattern matching is not the constructor as much as i understood, but i divided to both cases and didnt get what is wrong in this implementation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your pattern `(BNode x (BinaryTree l) (BinaryTree r))` is *not* a valid pattern. Indeed the data definition of a binary tree says:

```
data BinaryTree a = Nil | BNode a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)
```

so that means that `BNode` is a *data constructor* that packs three arguments. The *type* of the last two arguments is `BinaryTree a`, but you can not use types in pattern matching.

You thus should use `l` and `r` as variables for these parameters (or you can use the data constructors of the `BinaryTree a` type).

The same when you construct a `BinaryTree a` type. You call the constructor with `BNode x l r` with `x`, `l` and `r` the values, you do not specify the types here in the expression. You can specify the types, byt then you use the `::` operator.

You can thus fix your code with:

```
treeMap :: (a -> b) -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree b
treeMap f Nil  = Nil
treeMap f (BNode x l r) = BNode (f x) (treeMap f l) (treeMap f r)
```

or more elegant:

```
treeMap :: (a -> b) -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree b
treeMap f = go
    where go Nil = Nil
          go (BNode x l r) = BNode (f x) (go l) (go r)
```

That being said, you can let `ghc` derive the [**`Functor`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor) instance for you, by using the `DeriveFunctor` pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data BinaryTree a = Nil | BNode a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a) deriving Functor
```

The `treeMap` is just [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) with `f ~ BinaryTree` here.

Comment: It appears OP is confusing the type-level and value-level parts of the data type definition, which is no surprise because the Haskell98 syntax doesn’t really differentiate them. Lately I’ve been liking `GADTSyntax`, which lets you write `data BinaryTree :: Type -> Type where { Nil :: BinaryTree a; BNode :: a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a }`, and imo makes it clearer that `BinaryTree` is a *type* constructor and not a *data* constructor; it also makes it easier to introduce `GADTs` later on.